# rearrange the identity column value in sql server

Tags: sql-server, reset, identity-column

---

Please help me! I have a table will a identity field the value are,
for example, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11 .... etc.

I want to make it in a sequence, that is, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7... without using drop

Thanks

Comment: in addition to the answers below, there should be NO meaning attached to this identity field other than to uniquely identify a record.  It shouldn't be an invoice number or packing number or any other kind of number that MEANS something to someone.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. `identity` columns are not updatable. (or at least you can't in any sane way. You could delete all rows from the table then reinsert them with `IDENTITY_INSERT` on)

Also gaps in `identity` columns are just a fact of life that it's best to come to terms with! If you need a contiguous sequence of numbers for display purposes you can use `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Identities will alawys have gaps, they are expended for every record that gets rolled back as well as for records that are later deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a new field, make it idenity seed starting from 1, and then delete the old column and rename the new column (and then recreate all your FK references).

Comment: SQL Server doesn't allow changing the identity property on columns. You would need to drop the whole original column and create a new identity column. There would be no particular guarantee that the new ordering corresponded with that of the old.

Comment: @Martin - not true. Through the UI in SQL Server 2005/2008 manager, you can change the column remove the autonumber (identity) property of the column (select the table by right clicking on it and choose "Design").

Comment: That actually rebuilds the whole table behind the scenes. Click the "Script" icon in the toolbar to see the SQL it generates.

Comment: @Martin - you're right :(. I thought I distinctly remembered the script to show an 'alter column' statement, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this, and there is no reason why you should have to. You could however contruct a view to provide similar functionality:

```
CREATE VIEW MyTableView AS SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Identity) AS RowNum, * FROM MyTable
```

and then have your clients select from MyTableView instead.

If you need the view to have the same name as the table, so as to ensure backwards compatibility you can of course rename your table and then create a view with the old table name.

Comment: Whoops. Misread the question completely, answer should now be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's best solution.. try if you like it…

```
DECLARE @INC AS INTEGER 
SET @INC = 1 
WHILE (@INC <= 7582) --7582 is rowcount of table
BEGIN
    UPDATE YourTable
    SET    ID = @INC
    WHERE  ID = (
               SELECT MIN(ID) AS T
               FROM   YourTable
               WHERE  ID > @INC
           ) --ID=> Identity column
    SET @INC = @INC + 1
END
```

Note: before executing that you need to remove the identity insert to the column.

Answer (score 0):

DBCC CHECKIDENT (<'Table Name'>, RESEED, <'last sequence in table**'>)

** this will make the number plus 1 (+1) when entered. i.e needed the next to be 38 for new record so used 37 as this value.